# where are the individual dataproc spark logs?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Where are the dataproc spark job logs located? I know there are logs from the driver under "Logging" section but what about the execution nodes? Also, where are the detailed steps that Spark is executing logged (I know I can see them in the Application Master)? I am attempting to debug a script that seems to hang and spark seems to freeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE in Q3 2022: This answer is outdated, see [Dataproc YARN container logs location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195637/dataproc-task-logs-location) for the latest info.**

The task logs are stored on each worker node under `/tmp`.

It is possible to collect them in one place via yarn log aggregation. Set these properties at cluster creation time (via `--properties` with `yarn:` prefix):

- `yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true`
- `yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir=gs://${LOG_BUCKET}/logs`
- `yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds=-1`

Here's an article that discusses log management:

https://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/

Comment: which config file are these properties part of?

Comment: as the property itself says, yarn-site.xml