# Implement XGBoost in Scala Spark, dataproc zeppelin notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, xgboost, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to implement an xgboost model in scala, using zeppelin in dataproc (google cloud). This is the code I'm implementing:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, Row, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import scala.collection.mutable
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, _}
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineStage}
```

Adding deppendency (also added jar in zeppelin notebook dependencies)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ml.dmlc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xgboost4j-spark</artifactId>
    <version>0.72</version>
</dependency>
```

Dummy data:

```
val someData = Seq(
Row(8, 15 1),
Row(64, 25 1),
Row(27, 22 0)
)

val someSchema = List(
StructField("var1", IntegerType, true),
StructField("var2", IntegerType, true),
StructField("Classification", IntegerType, true)
)

val data= spark.createDataFrame(
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
StructType(someSchema)
)
```

Model implementation:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
val stringIndexer = new StringIndexer().
  setInputCol("Classification").
  setOutputCol("label").
  fit(data)
val labelTransformed = stringIndexer.transform(data).drop("Classification")
val vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler().
  setInputCols(Array("var1", "var2")).
  setOutputCol("features")
val xgbInput = vectorAssembler.transform(labelTransformed).select("features", "label")

import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostEstimator
val paramMap = Map[String, Any]("objective" -> "binary:logistic", "nworkers" -> 2)
val est = new XGBoostEstimator(paramMap)
val model = est.fit(xgbInput)
```

Everything works except for the very last line, where I get the following error:

```
Tracker started, with env={DMLC_NUM_SERVER=0, DMLC_TRACKER_URI=10.156.0.33, DMLC_TRACKER_PORT=9091, DMLC_NUM_WORKER=2}
ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostError: XGBoostModel training failed
  at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.ml$dmlc$xgboost4j$scala$spark$XGBoost$$postTrackerReturnProcessing(XGBoost.scala:406)
  at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$$anonfun$trainDistributed$4.apply(XGBoost.scala:356)
  at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$$anonfun$trainDistributed$4.apply(XGBoost.scala:337)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
  at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.trainDistributed(XGBoost.scala:336)
  at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostEstimator.train(XGBoostEstimator.scala:139)
  at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostEstimator.train(XGBoostEstimator.scala:36)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
  ... 69 elided
```

Once again, using scala on zeppelin through dataproc, spark version is 2.4.5.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: Full error logs:

```
Tracker started, with env={DMLC_NUM_SERVER=0, DMLC_TRACKER_URI=10.156.0.9, DMLC_TRACKER_PORT=9091, DMLC_NUM_WORKER=2}
ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostError: XGBoostModel training failed
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.ml$dmlc$xgboost4j$scala$spark$XGBoost$$postTrackerReturnProcessing(XGBoost.scala:406)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$$anonfun$trainDistributed$4.apply(XGBoost.scala:356)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$$anonfun$trainDistributed$4.apply(XGBoost.scala:337)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.trainDistributed(XGBoost.scala:336)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostEstimator.train(XGBoostEstimator.scala:139)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostEstimator.train(XGBoostEstimator.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.liftedTree1$1(<console>:63)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:61)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:74)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:76)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:78)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:80)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:82)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:84)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:86)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:88)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:90)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:92)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:94)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:96)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:98)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:100)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:102)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:104)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:106)
    at $line15134072657.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:108)
    at $line15134072657.$read.<init>(<console>:110)
    at $line15134072657.$read$.<init>(<console>:114)
    at $line15134072657.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line15134072657.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line15134072657.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line15134072657.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkScala211Interpreter.scalaInterpret(SparkScala211Interpreter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter$$anonfun$_interpret$1$1.apply(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:100)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter$$anonfun$_interpret$1$1.apply(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:94)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at scala.Console$.withOut(Console.scala:65)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter._interpret$1(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:94)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.interpret(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:125)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.NewSparkInterpreter.interpret(NewSparkInterpreter.java:147)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:73)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:103)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:632)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostError: XGBoostModel training failed
```

Comment: There must be more error messages or logs. Would you be able to paste full stack trace and logs? It's not clear what the cause actually is.

Comment: Are also able to provide more details about your environment like JDK/JRE version, Scala version, etc.

Comment: @yǝsʞǝla "Using Scala version 2.11.12, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_252"

Comment: @yǝsʞǝla Edited the original question to add the full error logs. I still have no idea how to solve my problem, do you think you can help?

Comment: I think we should see the stout/stderr or log output. That should have proper error.

Comment: @yǝsʞǝla how do I do that? I have no idea :(

Comment: On my local machine, I have to `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` to run the example.

Comment: @yǝsʞǝla I'm not being able to do that in zeppelin on the cloud

Comment: I don't have a setup like this so I can't really check but I'm sure the general execution log should be going somewhere (depending on verbosity level). Either stdout or some log file. Can you check https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/logging, http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342132/where-are-the-individual-dataproc-spark-logs to see if you can force it to log more stuff? It looks like you need to configure log4j to increase log level to INFO/DEBUG and maybe also dataproc logging.

Comment: Perhaps first try: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/driver-output#accessing_job_driver_output

Comment: What's the Dataproc image version you are using?