# Dataproc YARN container logs location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

i'm aware of the existence of this thread:
[where are the individual dataproc spark logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342132/where-are-the-individual-dataproc-spark-logs)

However if i ssh connect to a worker node vm and navigate to the /tmp folder this is all i see:
[image: ls /tmp]

Is anyone able to pinpoint me to the exact location?

also for some reason i can't navigate directly from UI to stdout/stderr of the single task as it says that i'm unable to reach the site whenever i try to access the logs from the link in the UI

Comment: Are you looking for Spark driver log or executor logs? How did you configure logs when creating the cluster? Did you use the default config?

Comment: i'm talking about specific executor logs, i used the default config

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer looks to be outdated.

If you are talking about the container logs, then:

1. On clusters with a 1.5 or newer image, Yarn log aggregation is enabled by default and the remote log directory is set to be the temp bucket for the cluster. You can look the location up under `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml`, and the configuration is `yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir`.
2. On clusters with a 1.4 or older image, log aggregation is not enabled by default, so the container logs will be under `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs` on the worker nodes where the containers were run.

Answer (score 2):

In **1.5** or newer versions, `dataproc:yarn.log-aggregation.enabled` is set to true by default. Under the hood, the `yarn.log-aggregation-enable` property in `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml` is set to `true`, and the container logs are controlled by the `yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir` property which is set to `gs://<cluster-tmp-bucket>/<cluster-uuid>/yarn-logs` by default. Check this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/staging-bucket) for more details on Dataproc tmp bucket.

In addition to dumping the logs at the location, there are several other ways to view the logs:

1. **YARN CLI**: If the cluster has not been deleted, SSH into the master node, then run `yarn logs -applicationId <app-id>`. If you are not sure about the app ID, run `yarn application -list -appStates ALL` to list all apps. This method works only when log aggregation is enabled.
2. **YARN Application Timeline server**: If you enabled [Component Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/dataproc-gateways) and the cluster has not been deleted, open the cluster's "YARN Application Timeline" link in the "WEB INTERFACES" tab of the cluster's web UI, find the application attemp and its containers, click the "Logs" link. This method works only when log aggregation is enabled.
3. **Cloud Logging**: YARN container logs are available in Cloud Logging even after the cluster is deleted.

   3.1) When `dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.yarn.container.enable` if `false` (which is the default) or the job is submitted through CLI e.g., `spark-submit` instead of Dataproc jobs API , it is under the `projects/<project-id>/logs/yarn-userlogs` log name of the **cluster** resource:

   ```
   resource.type="cloud_dataproc_cluster"
   resource.labels.cluster_name=<cluster-name>
   resource.labels.cluster_uuid=<cluster-uuid>
   log_name="projects/<project-id>/logs/yarn-userlogs"
   ```

   3.2) When `dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.yarn.container.enable` if `true`, it is under the `projects/<project-id>/logs/dataproc.job.yarn.container` log name of the **job** resource:

   ```
   resource.type="cloud_dataproc_job"
   resource.labels.job_id=<job_id>
   resource.labels.job_uuid=<job_uuid>
   log_name="projects/<project-id>/logs/dataproc.job.yarn.container"
   ```

In Dataproc **1.4** (deprecated) or older versions, the `yarn.log-aggregation-enable` property in `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml` is set to `fasle` by default, and the container logs are controlled by the `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` property which is set to `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs` by default.